# Trying to pass variable to a method within javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a method defined as:

```
public bool isQuantityInRange(int qty){}
```

But I need to access this from a JavaScript parser in a method similar to the following:

```
<input id="QuantityTextBox" name="quantity" type="number" value="@Model.Quantity" style="width: 50px" />

@using (Script.Foot())
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var validateQuantity = function () {

            if (!@Model.isQuantityInRange($("#QuantityTextBox").val())) {
                // do some stuff
            else {
                // do different stuff
        }

        $("#QuantityTextBox").change(validateQuantity);
        validateQuantity();
</script>
```

Granted, I can't access the value of the textbox from inside the cs statement. How do I do something like this?

Comment: Javascript runs in your client's browser. C# runs on the web server. To call a C# function from javascript, you would have to ajax the call. If isSquantityInRange() isn't very complicated, it'd probably make more sense to just reimplement it in javascript. (If it was complicated, you would make an ajax call to the function, then handle the response in the success handler.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 Calling controller method from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413069/mvc3-calling-controller-method-from-javascript) (Though I realized after I flagged, that that isn't an *exact* dup, in that it describes how to ajax-call a serverside function, but that question's function doesn't take any parameters. Quite similar, though - just pass in parameters using the "data" parameter in the ajax call.)